# Mono C# Thread Sleeps freeze when changing OS Time

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, mono

I'm developing a C# Mono application which is supposed to run constantly. It program has severals tasks which run in parallel and without stopping. 
To do so I'm using the .NET Task class.
Every task, once it's started, runs an infinite loop and performs its tasks inside this loop. Since almost every task I'm using doesn't need to work every millisecond, but just every 5-10 seconds, I put a `Thread.Sleep()` at the end of each infinite loop.
My internal Task run sequence looks like this:

```
while (Running)
{
   //Do the job
   Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

It actually works fine since I don't mind having an high precision about when the task wakes up and repeat its job. I also need to "slow down" every task a little bit to avoid the waste of CPU (my target machine is pretty low).

The **problem** is the, if the OS time changes for any reason (in particular, if it goes back) all my `Thread.Sleep` calls freeze and if I set the clock back to the original time everything start working again. I think it's due to the inner working of such call, but this actually force me to restart the whole program.

I even tried to replace the infinite-loop with a `Timer` (always from the .NET Framework) but I had the same problem: changing the OS clock causes my timer to stop firing.

How can I handle this problem ? Of course, the machine clock could change and I even have an NTP client which may change it at any time.

Comment: Known bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51766

Comment: Appears to be fixed in the alpha version of `5.0` : https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/4446